# How to access Firefox's DOM (or HTML content) from outside firefox

Tags: c++, html, firefox, dom

I have a question:

My program will search FireFox windows opened by user. When a user open Firefox and enter any site, I want to search for a keyword in that page's HTML content.

How can I access Firefox's Active Tab's DOM (or HTML content) from outside firefox using my C++ program.

Is it possible? If so, can you give me some idea or links?

If it is not possible, how can I copy text to clipboard within Firefox without installing / setting up anything?

Best regards,
Nuri Akman

Comment: Nuri, have you ever found a solution to this problem? I am looking for exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way to access the DOM of a web page inside Firefox from an external program. You can write an extension that implements some sort of IPC (using sockets or whatever) and communicate with that, but not built-in to Firefox.

Comment: Flash does it. How does it do it?

Comment: @Android, Flash is a plugin in firefox (which is similar to extensions)

Comment: @Motti, sorry but I have never programmed for Firefox, so I don't understand the distinction between a plugin/extension and ??? Could you please explain? Thanks.

Comment: @Android, an Extension extends the Firefox's functionality (Ad block, anti virus) a Plugin handles media types the Firefox doesn't know (Flash, Silverlight, video) they are both types of Addons and interact with the DOM the same way (via JavaScript, NPAPI or XPCOM)

Comment: @Motti, thank you very much. Your ability to articulate your knowledge is impressive. Another +1 for that.

Comment: @Motti, ditto on that last comment: +1 for very clearly articulating something I've never distinguished before

Comment: Microsoft's Internet Explorer does it (allows an application to use the DOM) with the WebBrowser and InternetExplorer objects. With Microsoft Edge we can use the WebView control to navigate to a page then inject JavaScript into the page that can communicate with the hosting application.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done through addons

Answer (score 1):

I had vary similar problem. I had to acces some page, then login user, and perform some actions. First I've tried to find something how to control DOM with external application/plugin, but finally I didn't find something useful. The only choise I found for me was controlling the user input. This can be done with Selenium project. You can find some usefull info in other stack overflow question:

[How do get Java to drive/control webkit/gecko?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062071/how-do-get-java-to-drive-control-webkit-gecko)