# Accessing the Firefox object model

Tags: firefox, dom, firefox-addon

Is it possible to access the DOM of a firefox page from a process outside of Firefox (in Windows.) It is possible to do with in IE via the accessibility interface and is a commonly used technique to access the IE browser without installing a BHO. But I was wondering if there is a similar technique available for Firefox, or must I install a firefox add on to make it available?

If the latter, does anyone have any pointers to a good place to start learning how to write a firefox add on?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access Firefox's DOM (or HTML content) from outside firefox.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096482/how-to-access-firefoxs-dom-or-html-content-from-outside-firefox)

Answer (score 1):

Since you can do virtually anything from an add-on, your easiest and best documented bet is to go for a Firefox add-on. There are numerous [tutorials](http://blog.mozilla.com/addons/2009/01/28/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/) available.

Doing it from "outside" probably means: creating an add-on for "inside" and communicate (using your own protocol or whatever) from the outside.

In this thread, it's explained that direct access is [not possible](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=365947&start=0&st=0&sk=t&sd=a). And here is a [duplicate of your question as SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096482/how-to-access-firefoxs-dom-or-html-content-from-outside-firefox).